# Keep only last value in list of lists when first item is duplicate in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I'd like to delete an item in a list of lists when the first value of that list is a duplicate of another item in the list.

Let's say I have this list:

```
[['A', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'],['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6']]
```

I'd like to only keep the last list with the value A as first index, like so:

```
[['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6']]
```

Comment: Do you want the resulting list to be in the same order as the original, or is it unimportant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a dict comprehension; since that builds up a dict by iterating over a list of values, you will always end up with the last duplicate. You can then simply take the values of the dict.

```
original = [['A', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'],['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6']]
d = {elem[0]: elem for elem in original}
result = list(d.values())
```

Comment: I was typing the exact same thing then i see your answer. hah plus +1 anyways. Good answer.

Comment: This only works if the ordering in resulting list is unimportant, as it won't keep the original ordering.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works like a charm. The order doesn't matter, as Blotosmetek commented.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby()` function:

```
import itertools
l = [['A', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'],['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6']]
result = [list(g)[-1] for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l), key=lambda x: x[0])]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6'], ['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['A', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'],['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6']]
l.pop(0)
print(l)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this way though it's not an efficient solution.

```
original = [['A', 'Value 1', 'Value 2'],['B', 'Value 3', 'Value 4'],['A', 'Value 5', 'Value 6'],]
first_element_count = []
for ls in original:
    first_element_count.append(ls[0])
seen, result = set(), []
len_first_element=len(first_element_count)-1
# finding the index of duplicate element and store the first index
while len_first_element>=0:
    item = first_element_count[len_first_element]
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
    else:
        result.append(len_first_element)

    len_first_element = len_first_element - 1
# removing the list from the list
for i in result:
    del original[i]
print(original)
```